# Can you set a minimum time a script will run for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add a minimum time my script will run for? It's a preloader, and sometimes the script runs longer than other times. I don't want to set a delay because if the site takes 20 minutes to load, adding an extra 10 seconds to it is just way too much loading time. Can I set this script so it has to run for a minimum of say 5 seconds?

```
var rafId = null,
    delay = 200,
    lTime = 0;

function scroll() {
    var e = $(window).scrollTop(),
        a = $(window).height(),
        n = e + a;
    $(".reveal").each(function () {
        var a = $(this);
        if (!a.hasClass("reveal_visible")) {
            var l = a.offset().top;
            l <= n && (l + a.height() < e ? a.removeClass("reveal_pending").addClass("reveal_visible") : (a.addClass("reveal_pending"), rafId || requestAnimationFrame(reveal)))
            $( "#someID" ).addClass( "someAnimationClass" );
        }
    })
}

function reveal() {
    rafId = null;
    var e = performance.now();
    if (e - lTime > delay) {
        lTime = e;
        var a = $(".reveal_pending");
        $(a.get(0)).removeClass("reveal_pending").addClass("reveal_visible")
    }
    $(".reveal_pending").length >= 1 && (rafId = requestAnimationFrame(reveal))
}
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".se-pre-con").delay(0).fadeOut("slow", function () {
        scroll(), $(window).scroll(scroll)
    })
});
```

Comment: `if the site takes 20 minutes to load`, if that is the case, 10 or 5 seconds is not going to make much difference..

Comment: What do you mean by "20 minutes to load"?

Comment: Because the execution of the function is launched with `$(window).load`, the script is already "finished" when it starts to run the functions (meaning it already went further to parse following scripts). If you want to go to next step after some time, you should be more precise what you want to do after and why you actually want to wait 5 sec

Comment: @Keith I was being dramatic. Sometimes the site may take 10 seconds to fully load the site if it has to download the assets. If you don't clear your cache, it'll take maybe 3 seconds.

Comment: why would you want a minimum time? Surely if the site loads instantly and the pre-loader can stop, then that's a good thing? What value does a minimum time constraint add?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  What exactly does the "preloader" do and why would you want it to run a *minimum* time?  Is it a 'loading...' page or a logo that you want to show?  (surely a *maximum* time would make more sense?)  You should be able to hook into when the loading has finished, so that it goes at the correct time.

Comment: There's a 0 to 100% loader and sometimes the site will fade out when it hits 50% and that looks really dumb

Comment: What does this 0-100% loader do, surely you should fade out when it's hit 100%.  IOW: The 100% should be the trigger for fading out, then you won't have 50% on the screen when it's fading.